Derivatives of multivariate Gaussian
I do not understand how to take the second derivative of the Gaussian:

While I am certain that the result is correct, I do not understand how to get from the first to the second line of the second-derivative calculation. Using the product rule is clear, but where does the transpose come from? The answer "it is required for the dimensions to fit" seems unsatisfactory. I am sure there is some matrix rule that I do not know of. The matrix cookbook (https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) does not suggest to transpose anything.


Write out the exponent explicitly and use the chain rule.

@Aruralreader: I do not see how this answers my question regarding the transpose.

@Aruralreader: My question is not how the second, left $\Sigma^{-1}\cdot (x-\mu)$ appears in the third line of the calculation of the 2nd derivative. My question is, how the transposing "T" appears.

$
\def\c{\cdot}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\green#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\blue#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\RLR#1{\red{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$For typing convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
u=\mu,\qq M=M^T=\Sigma^{-1},\qq p=\nabla g \\
}$$
In terms of these definitions, the gradient (which you have no problem with) is
$$\eqalign{
\def\g{\grad gx}
p &= \g  \:=\: -g\;M\LR{x-u} \\
}$$
from which one obtains the following expression for the differential of $g$
$$\eqalign{
\p g &= p^T\p x \;=\; -g\;\LR{x-u}^TM\;\p x \\
}$$
Now let's calculate the differential and gradient
of $p\:$ (i.e. the Hessian of $g$)
$$\eqalign{
\p p &= -M\LR{x-u}\,\red{\p g} \;-\; g\;M\:\red{\p x} \\
 &= -M\LR{x-u}\RLR{-g\;\LR{x-u}^TM\;\p x} \;-\; g\;M\:\red{\p x} \\
 &= g\;M\LR{x-u}\LR{x-u}^TM\;\p x \;-\; g\;M\:\p x \\
\grad px 
 &= g\;M\LR{x-u}\LR{x-u}^TM \;-\; g\;M \\
}$$
${\sf Note\ that}\ g\ {\rm and}\ \partial g$ are scalars and can be moved around freely in these expressions, but the other variables represent vectors and matrices, so they cannot be moved around as easily.

Thank you! I am not there yet, unfortunately. 1. Why is $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ an (upright) column vector and $\frac{d g}{d x}$ a row vector. Maybe I do not know the difference between $\partial$ and $d$. 2. If $\partial$ and $d$ are different, how can you flip between them in the last line?

@Make42 I changed my notation $d\to\partial$ to be consistent with the Cookbook. You can interpret $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ as either a row or column vector, but then you must choose between a transposition or a dot product when you multiply it by another vector (or matrix). Choosing a consistent notation is the key.  Assuming that all vectors are column vectors is a common (and consistent) choice.

Ok, that is also my understanding. Taking about being consistent: In the second row of formulas your write $p=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$, which is a column vector. But one row of formulas below you write $p^T=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ if you multiply both sides with $\partial x$. Can you explain the discrepancy?

Given two column vectors $(a,b)$ their inner product requires either a transposition or a dot product, i.e. $;a^Tb,$ or $,a\cdot b.;$

I know. In my notation, I always mean matrix multiplication which requires a transposition. But if I get in a derivation $x \cdot y$, where $x$ and $y$ are vectors of the same length and "$\cdot$" is the matrix product, then I most likely did a mistake somewhere. What I cannot do is just transpose either $x$ or $y$ as seems fit. At least that is my understanding, because $x^T \cdot y \neq x \cdot y^T$. I know what your are aiming at when you did what you did, but I do not see why it is legit. This is the discrepancy that I mentioned in my latest comment.

I cannot see how you get from $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=p$ (second line) to $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=p^T$ (third line).

@Make42 There is no discrepancy. The second line defines
$,p\doteq\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right)$
and the third line utilizes its transpose
$$p^T=\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right)^T$$
You are simply mistaken to interpret that the third line uses
$$p^T=\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right)$$

The second line defines $p = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ I agree. The third line is
$$
\partial g = p^T \partial x
$$
which I understand to be
$$
\Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = p^T
$$
How do get the left-hand side here to be transposed? Or in other words, how does
$$
\big(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\big)^T = p^T
\overset{?}{\Leftrightarrow} \partial g = p^T \partial x
$$
