How do I take the derivative of this formula?
I want to calculate the derivatives of the following matrix valued function by going back to the definition of derivative in the usual sense of limits, following the ideas of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2990945/340174.
(Note that $S=S^T$.)
$$f(x,m,S) = \exp(-0.5 (x-m)^T S (x-m) ) S (x-m)$$
then for some small $t > 0$, and some $y$ (having the same dimensions as $x$ and $m$), we calculate the directional derivative in the "direction" of $y$:
With
$$
f(x+ty,m,S) = \exp(-0.5 (x-m+ty)^T S (x-m+ty) ) S (x-m+ty)
$$
$$
= \exp(-0.5 (x-m)^T S (x-m) - ty^T S (x-m) - 0.5ty^T S y) S (x-m+ty)
$$
$$
= \exp(-0.5 (x-m)^T S (x-m) ) \exp(-ty^T S (x-m)) \exp(- 0.5ty^T S y) S (x-m) + \exp(-0.5 (x-m)^T S (x-m) ) \exp(-ty^T S (x-m)) \exp(- 0.5ty^T S y) S ty
$$
we get
$$\frac{\partial f(x,m,S)}{\partial x}(y)
= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+ty,m,S) - f(x,m,S)}{t}
$$
$$
= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{t} \bigg[
\exp(-0.5 (x-m)^T S (x-m) ) \exp(-ty^T S (x-m)) \exp(- 0.5ty^T S y) S (x-m) + \exp(-0.5 (x-m)^T S (x-m) ) \exp(-ty^T S (x-m)) \exp(- 0.5ty^T S y) S ty - \exp(-0.5 (x-m)^T S (x-m) ) S (x-m)
\bigg]
$$
with $\exp(... t ...)$ going to 1
$$
= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{t} \bigg[
\exp(-0.5 (x-m)^T S (x-m) ) S (x-m) + \exp(-0.5 (x-m)^T S (x-m) ) S ty - \exp(-0.5 (x-m)^T S (x-m) ) S (x-m)
\bigg]
$$
$$
= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{t} \bigg[
\exp(-0.5 (x-m)^T S (x-m) ) S ty
\bigg]
$$
$$
= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\bigg[
\exp(-0.5 (x-m)^T S (x-m) ) S y
\bigg]
$$
I am certain this is wrong, but I just do not see where I did the mistake or the mistakes.

You are forcing yourself to reprove the product and chain rules, which will be a mess.

@TedShifrin: I tried it the "conventional" way, but I am not sure how the transposition comes to pass and the single answer I got is missing the point: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4932565/derivatives-of-multivariate-gaussian

Well, just do $\dfrac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} f(x+ty,m.S)$ using the usual differentiation rules.

@TedShifrin: I apologize, but I am lost regarding what you mean. (1) What does your notation $\frac{d}{dt} \big|_t=0$ mean? In what way is it different to my expression with the limit? (2) What do you mean by using the usual differentiation rules?
